# JBoss deployment failures after server reboots due to missing ojdbc6.jar

Tags: deployment, jboss

On our development server there are half dozen or so successfully deployed apps.
Every Sunday night, the server (not sure if it is JBoss or the actual server) is restarted.  As JBoss tries to redeploy all the apps, one fails and then all are rolled back.

I *think* what is happening is that one application depends on ojdb6.jar, which is also deployed as an app, but the application is trying to be deployed before JBoss tries to deploy the oracle driver.

I followed this article http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=350 for installing the driver and followed the "Install as a deployment"

Should I have the server guys as the driver as a module?
Or does the error lye within how my application depends on the db driver?

Comment: are you establishing connections directly from this application?  Would you not be better of moving the connection/pooling to the application server and use a DataSource JNDI reference in your actual application's connection settings?

Comment: yes, I am connecting directly from this application.  Your suggestion may work, but there are a ton of internal applications.  And each developer of these apps has their own db connection to their app.  We share the JBoss server.  It may be too much to ask the admin of Jboss to setup a JDNI every time a new application is deployed.  Plus, this would expose our credentials to the Server admin who is a contractor.